# When using two way binding in angular, when are the binded variables actually available?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a directive that uses two-way binding.My directive looks like this:

`bankSearch.directive('bankSearch',
            function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: {
                        bankDetail: '='
                    },
                    templateUrl: "angular/views/self_signup/bank_search.html",
                    link: function(scope) {
                        //Now when link function runs, scope.bankDetail is undefined.
                    }
                }
            });`

Html of template-url:

```
`<div class="row-fluid">
      <input id="ifsc-code" class="span12" type="text" name="ifscCode"
           ng-model="bankDetail.bankBranch.ifscCode"
           should-be-ifsc
           ng-keypress="onPressEnter($event, bankSearch.ifscCode.$valid)">
 </div>`
```

This is how I'm using the directive:

```
`<bank-search
      bank-detail="bankSearchModel.bankDetail">
 </bank-search>`
```

I was under the impression that link function runs after linking(watchers setup) is done. If I'm correct then why am I getting undefined for scope.bankDetail inside my link function.

I'm new to Angular. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does the HTML that is using the directive look like?

Comment: You should have <bank-search bank-detail="model" /> in your HTML, where 'model' is defined on scope.

Comment: I have updated the post with how I'm using my directive and template.

Comment: Yeah, the HTML looks correct so my best guess is that the model actually is undefined. Try adding `{{ bankSearchModel.bankDetail }}` outside of the '<bank-search>` element and see if it prints anything. If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: Once the link function is executed, then the binding is working fine. But inside link function, binded variables are undefined. Is the linking done after link function is executed?

Comment: @ivarni bankSearchModel.bankDetail outside bank-search prints the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be `bankSearchModel.bankDetail` defines after directive is rendered. In case it is loaded from $http or something else. Try

```
link: function(scope) {
    scope.$watch('bankDetail', function(val){
        console.log(val);
    });
}
```

And you'll see all changes of that variable.